# How to display two List<ApplicationInfo> and ArrayList<String> in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have a list one ApplicationInfo type and another ArrayList of  String type. I want to list these both in listView. Can I extend both ArrayAdapter (ApplicationInfo) and ArrayAdapter(String) to ApplicationAdapter.class? Here's my current code which displays only the ApplicationInfo only.

ApplicationAdapter.class

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {

    private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
    private Context context;
    private PackageManager packageManager;
    public ImageView addview;

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
        this.context = context;
        this.appsList = appsList;
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        if (null == view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_list_row, null);
        }

        ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
        if (null != data) {
            TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
            addview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.add_icon);

            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
            packageName.setText(data.packageName);
            iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
            addview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ads);

        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

AllAppsActivity.class

```
public class AllAppsActivity extends ListActivity implements Serializable {

    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;
    public ImageView addview;
    public ArrayList<String> addblock_list;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mboolean = false;

        addblock_list = new ArrayList<String>(100);

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i= i + 1) {
            addblock_list.add("addblock");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        packageManager = getPackageManager();

        new LoadApplications().execute();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        addview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.add_icon);

        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);

        if(addblock_list.get(position).equals(app.packageName)) {
            addview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ads);
            addblock_list.set(position, "addblock");

            Toast.makeText(AllAppsActivity.this, "removed "+app.packageName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            addview.setImageResource(R.drawable.adsblock);
            addblock_list.set(position, app.packageName);

            Toast.makeText(AllAppsActivity.this, "added "+app.packageName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(AllAppsActivity.this, R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);

            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(AllAppsActivity.this, null, "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

    }

}
```

I checked the internet, I suppose I have to use something similar to this:

I changed my code as follows in AllAppsActivity Class

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        applist = checkForLaunchIntent( packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        HashMap<Integer,Object> yourHash = new HashMap<Integer,Object>();
        yourHash.put(1,applist);
        yourHash.put(2,addblock_list);
        listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(AllAppsActivity.this,
                R.layout.snippet_list_row,yourHash);
        return null;



    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setListAdapter(listadaptor);
        progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

My ApplicationAdapter.class

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<Integer,Object>>{

private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
private Context context;
private PackageManager packageManager;
public ImageView addview;
private ArrayList<String> addblock_list;
private HashMap<Integer,Object> yourHash;



public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        HashMap<Integer,Object> yourHash) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(context,textViewResourceId);

    this.context = context;
    this.yourHash = yourHash;
    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();


        List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = (List<ApplicationInfo> ) yourHash.get(1);
         ArrayList<String> addblock_list=( ArrayList<String> ) yourHash.get(2);




}


@Override
public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
    return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
}..........
```

I am new to android and java .

1. Is it proper of me to define HashMap(Integer ,Object),when I have an list and an arrayList  ?
2. i dont know about constructor and super()? super is not taking the myHash argument ?

Please enlighten me by giving telling me how to do this, send me the code for doing. Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a hashmap is a type of container that can save different objects, sorted by a tag.
 you could set that hashmap on a static class to access it from everywhere or pass it by parameter to your adapter ( recommended).

take a look at the official docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html

example implementation:

```
 // create an arrayList to store values
35
        ArrayList<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();
36
        listOne.add("Blue");
37
        listOne.add("Black");
38
        listOne.add("Brown");
39

40
        // create list two and store values
41
        ArrayList<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
42
        listTwo.add("Pink");
43
        listTwo.add("Purple");
44

45
        // put values into map
46
        multiMap.put("B color", listOne);
47
        multiMap.put("P color", listTwo);
```

and here you can find a similar question that resolves the different  types question:

[Hashmap holding different data types as values for instance Integer, String and Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599317/hashmap-holding-different-data-types-as-values)

Comment: hey I have an list and an ArrayList , so i defined it as HashMap HashMap<Integer,Object> . Is it okay ? plz check the question answer my doubts  , i edited it . Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Is it proper of me to define HashMap(Integer ,Object),when I have an list and an arrayList ?  - **yes, they are both objects, it's a quite fine way to do it.**
    i dont know about constructor and super()? **super is not taking the myHash argument ?  a constructor is  the creation method of a class, and super calls the superclass. you should learn a bit about classes and inheritance in java.**

Comment: Thanks @CptEric . I converted the list to Arraylist and created an HashMap(Integer,ArrayList) and was successful retrieving both arrays in ApplicationAdapter.Class . I am having issues with another problem , can you please check it out . [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604768/battery-is-draining-because-of-alarmmanager-and-broadcast-receiver-i-think)