# Battery is draining because of alarmManager and Broadcast Receiver I think

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, battery

HI i have an app like a applock (not applock) , which checks for current app running with list of selected apps by a user , if it matches then I hv my code . I have an service which doesnt have any loops  calls StartupReceiver .Class(broadcast Receiver) which inturn calls CheckRunningApplicationReceiver.Class(broadcastReceiver) which checks the current activity . I am calling CheckActivity for every 0.5 second . And i do lot of storing and retrieving strings in internal storage inside the CheckActivity.Class . Its draining my battery . Help me .

MyService.class

```
public class MyService extends Service{
private static final String TAG = "MyService";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {      

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

//Note: You can start a new thread and use it for long background processing from here.
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        getBaseContext().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(
                new Intent("StartupReceiver_Manual_Start")); 

    return START_STICKY;

}}
```

StartupReceiver.Class

```
public class StartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
static final String TAG = "SR";
final int startupID = 1111111;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    try{

            Intent i7 = new Intent(context, CheckRunningApplicationReceiver.class);                        
               PendingIntent ServiceManagementIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    startupID, i7, 0);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 
                    500, ServiceManagementIntent);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Exception : "+e);
        }}
      }  
    }
```

}

CheckRunningApplicationReceiver.Class

```
 public class CheckRunningApplicationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements Serializable{




@Override
public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent anIntent) {

    //I do lot of things here . 
   //I am not using any thread here ( i dont know about threads ) .
   //I am checking internet connectivity here , storing an retrieving
   //arraylist , strings from internal storage here , getting current 
   //running app and checking with the arraylist . 
}
```

- Here are the things I observed , when I put alarm time as 10ms , my phone when connected to laptop , detection of phone phone happened after 15 seconds delay , even when transferring files through bluetooth ,there was a delay . now i am calling for 0.2 second . So I cannot observe these problems. Whats the reason for this ?
- I am storing arraylist and few strings in the internal storage . Should I be using Shared Preferences instead?
- Is there any broadcast receiver which tells me if current running app is changed ?
- Should i be using a infinite loop inside a service instead of using alarm Manager?
- How to stop the CHeckRunningApp.Class when the phone is locked or phone goes to sleep ?
- Solution for battery drain?

Comment: The battery would drain fast for sure if you would keep on polling at 0.2 seconds.

Comment: But I need to check when an user starts an app , if the  app matches with the list . So how do i do it without without calling it for short time ? Is there any different approach ?

Answer (score 0):

> But I need to check when an user starts an app

There is no way to detect the new application launch (I don't think there's any such Broadcast receiver to support that), you can write a service which would keep on polling to look for running application using Activity Manager, but I don't think that would be efficient. You have to compromise, eith poll a a slow rate or Battery may drain fast.

Please have a look at this project - https://github.com/twinone/AppLocker

Comment: If i make use only of service instead of alarmManager and broadcast receiver ,will it make a difference ? Any idea how does apps like applock does that ?

Comment: I made another observation . If i delete the code present in CheckRunningApps.class , i.e though the class is being called 0.5 seconds my battery is not draining . So i need to divide my work and run them in different receivers and multiple threads i guess . Can anyone tell me about multiple  threads?

Comment: So i have an arraylist . i am using Gson.jar to convert into json string and storing it using shared preferenes . Now my battery is draining whose percentage is same as that of phone ideal state percentage . Is there anyway i can improve it ?

Comment: The problem is that your doing something every half a second, and if you would keep on doing it it would consume battery for sure.

Answer (score -1):

Yes I got it . For every half a second , if you check internet connection , turn it on or off , check current running activity , battery doesnt get drained . 
Battery gets drained if you are storing or retrieving in the internal storage . 
Now i am using shared preferences and I am not having an battery drain . Yeah!